# SIGPIPE not being generated immediately after 1st send

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, send, sigpipe

I want to know whether its possible for tcp socket to report any broken pipe error immediately. Currently i am catching the sigpipe signal at the client side when server goes down ... but i found that the sigpipe signal is generated
only after 2nd msg is sent from client to server . what could be the possible reason for this?? If the other socket end went down , then the 1st send must return sigpipe .. y isnt that signal generated immediately..??
Is there any possible explanation to this peculiar behaviour?? And any possible way to get around this??

Comment: I think you're asking too much...

Comment: How would you detect the server went down? BTW how did it go down?

Comment: A closed connection is signaled when attempting to read from the connection.

Comment: @jpalecek .. well i killed the server process by ctrl +c option .. in real time applications it can go down due to many reasons and boot up ..

Comment: When the client sends msg it receives SIGPIPE error , but only after executing send() twice .. Read will also generate but currently the client is not reading anything... @todda ... LMAO!!

Answer (score 1):

The TCP stack will only throw an error after some number of retransmission attempts.  IIRC, the TCP retransmission timer is initialized to some small number of seconds and the number of retransmissions is typically 5-10.  The protocol does not support any other means of detecting a peer that has become unreachable during a data exchange, (ie. someone tripped over the server power cable).

Comment: *The TCP stack will only throw an error after some number of retransmission attempts.*   can you tell me what is that error and after approx what time will tcp throw that error.

Comment: The acual error thrown can vary - you may get ECONNRESET or ECONNABORTED or ETIMEDOUT.  Depends on how, and if, the server and/or router/s go away and come back up, and when.  The time taken before the error is issued is OS/configuration dependent, but it's going to be tens of seconds on most OS.  It has to be long in case some router somewhere is trying to establish an alternative route, eg. by dialling a modem or trying to get a slot on a microwave link.  The protocol will try very hard to deliver the data somehow and it has to be given time to try to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `SO_KEEPALIVE` option may speed up broken link detection.

Comment: `SO_KEEPALIVE` generally is sent every two hours or some such. I would  not recommended that as a way to check connection status.

Comment: It is adjustable, but no, I'm not recommending it, I'm covering options :)

Comment: @user1158242, I guess if you adjust it using `setsockopt`, then not. If you adjust systemwide then, obviously, yes.

Comment: can u give me the syntax to set the particular socket (and not the entire system) to give a signal or error within 1sec of the server going down ...

Comment: Look it up here, http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/ but one second sounds like asking for too much indeed.

Comment: not at all ... i dont know how they implement real time applications , they must be detecting and reconnecting at much faster speeds, some one who has worked on such things might be able to tell us.

Comment: It sounds more like udp, I'd say.

Comment: 'real time' applications have to accept and handle network latency.  A video streamer might, for example, maintain a large queue of frames to allow sufficient time for a typical reconnect/resync without any noticeable communication break by the user.  The cost for this is latency - the movie is being viewed seconds later than is actually being received.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know whether its possible for tcp socket to report any broken pipe error immediately

The other end of the pipe is across a network. That network could be slow and unreliable. So one end of the pipe can never instantly tell whether its partner still there. The delay could be quite long, so the O/S is also likely to do some bufferring. These considerations make it practically impossible to immediately detect a broken pipe.

> And any possible way to get around this

But why would you want to? The pipe could be broken at any time during trans mission, so you have to handle the general case anyway.

Comment: If not immediately then ASAP would do ..yes but the general case is that sigpipe is returned after 2nd send , and if someone were giving config commands, then there is a possibility that socket gets broken just before he sends the last config cmd and he wudnt know he missed it..

Comment: @Srinivas "just before he sends the last config cmd and he wudnt know he missed it" so your *real* interest is knowing, on the sender getting a a `SIGPIPE`, how much data has been received by the receiver? Knowing that isn't much use, because the sender probably really wants to know whether the recevier has completed acting upon the commands send. For that you need to build a protocol on top on TCP/IP, which has the receiver sending acknowledgements for completed commands.

Comment: I want the client to reconnect automatically, which is y i am depending on a signal handler to do the job .. yeah der is also a ack response from the receiver after he successfully completes execution ... but say if the client doesnt receive ack for the last cmd , he wudnt know whether it was due to broked socket or due to the incompetency of the receiver to complete the cmd...